# Changing shown URL with a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How can I change the displayed URL with a firefox addon without actually changing the page location? The reason for this is so I can load a local html file but not show the actual local path in the url bar.

Example user experience: The user clicks on a button in firefox, which opens a local html file. Instead of showing the path, it shows "Local HTML File" in the address bar. The title and content of the page are as specified by the html file.

Edit: I want to build an addon that does this , not find an addon to help me do this.

Comment: If you just want to do this on a local machine, maybe you could just run a webserver locally and add an entry to your hosts file. Regardless, you're looking for a firefox add-on to do this, which is hardly a programming question.. unless you want to build one.

Comment: @Evert: I appreciate the advice, but I do not think that a good solution would be to distribute a webserver to users. I am looking to build an addon that does this. When I say 'local file' I am actually referring to a file bundled with the addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file is bundled with the addon, it usually has a "[chrome URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL)" (nothing to do with Google Chrome) which you have some control over. Otherwise you could just change the URL bar directly: `document.getElementById('urlbar').value = '...'`